# Is there an updated version of 'where_clauses' method for Arel in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

So I updated Rails from 4.0.1 to 4.1.16 and I'm getting errors along the lines of:

```
Failure/Error: self.published.arel.where_clauses.join(' AND ')

  NoMethodError:
    undefined method `where_clauses' for #<Arel::SelectManager:0x007fd773b1dd50>
```

I looked through the documentation for Arel (using version 5.0.1.20140414130214) and I can't find the same method. Has it been replaced and if so, with what?

Answer (score 1):

> Has it been replaced and if so, with what?

It was [deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cefad1e2139c4bba6e45f3281a6d54394aaeb366) and then [removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/27330ebae9537dd5503b10d3c0e6f422a38bd9c8) with no replacement. Seems that you need to review the logic of the places, which used `where_clauses` and reimplement those parts of the application using the current [existing methods](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/SelectManager#where_sql-instance_method) of arel